# Google cloud deployment manager update Container cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to create a Google Cloud Deployment Manager configuration to deploy and manage a Google Cloud Container cluster. So far, creating a configuration to create a cluster works, however updating fails. If I change a setting, the execution of the script fails with an error message I can't decipher:

```
 code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/my-first-cluster/resources/my-first-test-cluster-setup
  message: 
 '{"ResourceType":"container.v1.cluster","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid
JSON payload received. Unknown name \"cluster\": Cannot find field.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"description":"Invalid
JSON payload received. Unknown name \"cluster\": Cannot find field."}]}],"statusMessage":"Bad
Request","requestPath":"https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/*****/zones/europe-west1-b/clusters/my-first-cluster"}}'
```

The relevant configuration:

```yaml
resources:
- name: my-first-test-cluster-setup
  type: container.v1.cluster
  properties:
    zone: europe-west1-b
    cluster:
      name: my-first-cluster
      description: My first cluster setup
      nodePools:
        - name: my-cluster-node-pool
          config:
            machineType: n1-standard-1
          initialNodeCount: 1
          autoscaling:
            enabled: true
            minNodeCount: 3
            maxNodeCount: 5
          management:
            autoUpgrade: true
            autoRepair: true
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this is a bug in Deployment Manager which means that it is not able to update GKE clusters. The bug is reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38131324). It has the same strange 'unknown name "cluster"' message that you see.

There is no suggestion on the ticket about workarounds or resolution.

We have seen this same problem when updating a different cluster property.

Comment: Hi, @Ben ! can you take a look at this question, please!               https://stackoverflow.com/q/47149954/7644562